# IE(Version 11) not rendering the input type number

Tags: jquery, css, html

i'm facing an issue in rendering the html input type number. In IE number type becomes a textbox. In other browser like chrome,Firefox and Opera rendering is perfect.

```
<input id="nbStopInterval" type="number" min="1" max="180" step="1" value="15" required="true"/>
```

above given is my HTML.
Is anyone knows what is exactly happening in IE.

Thanks,
 Ajith

Comment: IE doesn't support type=number attribute. But you can try with Polyfil http://html5please.com/#number

Comment: @Sven yeah..its a duplicate :)

Comment: @KarthikSivakumar Thank you. but i dont want to use any external scripts.

Comment: Then from my understanding. There is no any direct way of implementing this. To achive this you need to add some extra libraries!